# How to Structure Projects for Multiple Xamarin Apps

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, shared-libraries, solution, ms-project

My team is working on translating several legacy mobile applications to Xamarin Forms apps.  Currently each application is in its own solution, which is not ideal when it comes to the fact that they all use a common set of backend software libraries.  We were planning to consolidate all the smaller solutions into a single solution, containing the apps as well as the common libraries.

However, one of my teammates brought up a valid concern about how with a single Xamarin Forms app, several projects could get generated (core, Android, iOS, etc.), with the eventual result of a generally unwieldy solution.  I agree with him that the current setup probably would not scale too well as we add more apps -- even if we group projects in solution folders, Visual Studio will eventually slow to a crawl after a certain amount of projects exist in the solution.

So we are considering just going back to having each app in its own solution, each solution containing the few Xamarin Forms projects for that app, as mentioned above.  But this brings us back to the question of how to reasonably manage the shared library code.  My current thought would be to just use shared project(s) for the libraries, or maybe assemble them into NuGet package(s) the app solutions would consume.  Am I on the right track here, or does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Hi there, interested to know how your experience with this went. Potentially facing the same scenario where multiple apps may use the same code, views, viewmodels and thinking whether this can be accommodated in the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to manage a shared code project using subtrees, submodules, NuGet packages, etc. There are pros and cons to each so it's best to decide based on the expected use case for that project.

Subtrees essentially take a copy of the remote repo and pull it into the parent repo. This makes it easy to pull in changes from the remote repo but if changes are expected to be pushed back it can be significantly more difficult since it has no knowledge of the remote repo. While it is possible to push changes back it can take a significant among of time to do depending on the amount of history of the repos.

Submodules are similar to subtrees except that instead of taking a copy it tracks the remote repo based on a specific commit it's pointed to. This essentially can be thought of as another repo inside of the parent that makes pushing changes back to the remote repo much easier but at the cost of making pulling/updating from it a little bit more difficult.

NuGet packages are extremely convenient to install, update, and release to others without having to make the source code public, but that comes with a bit more initial setup to generate each package version and comes at the cost of making it more difficult to debug than with the actual source code. This is particularly a great option if the shared code library will be distributed to others.

For most projects, if changes are expected to be potentially made to that shared project from a consuming one I'd recommend a repo for each project and set up the shared one as a submodule in each. It does take a bit of learning to get used to the different processes of checking out and updating a submodule but actually isn't all that difficult and worth learning the few git commands required. The [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) provide a great example of how to get started using submodules.

Comment: I haven't really considered subtrees, but this is a helpful summary.  We are probably going to be doing a bit of work on both sides of the interface, so probably not our best option.

Comment: I had considered submodules.  I think they are a decent option, but my team is just getting introduced to git and I don't think using a more advanced feature will be a good idea right now.

Comment: NuGet packages is what I am leaning towards.  I've done some initial feasibility demos and it seems like it could work with our setup.  Apparently it is in fact possible to put the debugging symbols in, so that helps.  I might ease into it by starting with an "Add Existing Project" to solution route, which has roughly the same solution/project layout, and later switching to NuGet.

Comment: Yeah if your team is starting to learn git I would probably start with NuGet packages and then maybe learn how to use submodules yourself first to be able to teach your team. The one sln approach isn't the worst option, but that can certainly get pretty cumbersome. They have recently come out with [sourcelink](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink) to help debug NuGet packages, which I haven't tried yet but if it works well it may make debugging packages so easy it may not be worth switching to submodules.